Advanced AJAX Product Filters for WooCommerce кнопка сброс фильтров
помогите пожалуйста. я создал фильтр и он работает, но нужно сделать кнопку сброс фильтра , которой я так понимаю нет в плагине
Я сначала попробовал сам, в фильтре увидел, что при выборе какого-нибудь параметра, в коде рядом с ним появляется selected="selected",попробовал его удалить, но его не получилось удалить
 $('.clear').on('click', function () {
    $('option:selected', this).removeAttr('selected');
});



для начала попробуй изучить настройки плагина.

нашел кнопку, все,аллилуя), все просто
